# Possible number of passwords combinations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

We have been given the following question for our mock exam:

Each student has a password, which is 6 characters long and each character
is either a digit or a lower case letter. Each password must contain at least
ONE letter. How many possible passwords are there?

```
26 lower case letters
10 digits
6 characters long
At least one letter
```

The way I understood, is that it would be easier using inclusion-exclusion, therefore:

$36^6 - 10^6 $ = 2175782336

However another student mentioned it would be:

$36^6 - 10^5 $ = 2176682336

And I also heard:

$36*36*36*36*36*26$ = 1572120576

I think the word "at least ONE letter" is throwing me off a bit. Would anyone mind explaining this to me, please?

Comment: I think your answer is correct.  There are $36^6$ possible strings of $6$ digits/letters.  Of those, there are $10^6$ strings that contain only digits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding, and your solution of $36^6 - 10^6$, are correct.

---

The problem with the answer of $36 \times 36 \times 36 \times 36 \times 36 \times 26$ is that it does not account for the number of different arrangements that are possible. This would be the solution if the password rules were:

- 6 characters long
- The first *five* characters are lower case letters or digits
- The sixth character is a non-digit character

However in the actual rules, the restriction on digits is that *at least one character* has to be a non-digit. There is no specification of which digit this has to be.

---

Inclusion-exclusion is the perfect way to approach the problem. There are $36^6$ sequences of six digits satisfying the first three rules you posted. The fourth rule, `At least one letter`, rules out all the passwords that are composed entirely of digits. There are $10^6$ of these, so this can be subtracted from the $36^6$ figure. The person who suggested subtracting $10^5$ either made a mistake, or got slightly confused.

Comment: Thanks @Alira! Glad I'm taking the right approach for this one.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is the correct one and your explanation for it is correct.

The answer of $36^5\cdot 26$ is the number of passwords who **start** with a letter... but what you want to count doesn't care necessarily *where* the letters appear.  (*Equivalently, it is also the number of passwords who end with a letter*)

The answer of $26\cdot 6\cdot 36^5$ is wrong because it makes a distinction about which is the "*first*" "guaranteed" letter placed when such a distinction is impossible when looking at the final result.  The value is even larger than the number of strings when no restrictions were in place.

The answer of $36^6-10^5$ makes little sense how such an error occurred... likely just a typo.

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz! Yep! It is now very clear to me! Thank you both for you help on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is totally correct. Since you must remove all the possible combinations where not even a single alphabet is used. To do this you must subtract $10^6$ and not $10^5$.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution of $36^6$ - $10^6$ is correct as $36∗36∗36∗36∗36∗26$ would only be applicable if the ***last*** digit of the password was required to be a lowercase letter.